# "x.rsplit()" with multiple delimiters in Python

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
x.rsplit("+", 1)[-1]
```

The string will be splitted at the end **once** if "+" is in the way.

Example:

12+345+**32** --> **32**

But I want it to split if "+", "-" or "/" are in the way (Not just with "+" but also with "-" or "/")

Example:

12+345 **-** 32 --> 32

or

12+345 **/** 32 --> 32

How can I add multiple limits when splitting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regex to split the string based on the operators and return the rightmost result:

```py
re.split(r"[+-/]", x)[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting into a list you can extract the last "chunk" with precise regex matching:

```
import re

s = '12+345 - 32'
res = re.search(r'(?<=[+-/])[^+-/]+$', s).group()
print(res)
```

---

```
32
```